# Log parser not reading the new fields included in IIS Log

Tags: parsing, iis, logging, logparser

I use log parser 2.2 to read the IIS log and copy the log into a database. Initially IIS log was having the default fields and I was able to copy the log in to database. Now I included one more field in IIS log but the log parser does not return the details of new column. Can anyone help to make log parser to read the additional fields along with the old log files?

Following query is used to read IIS log.

```
select * from C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC3\*.*
```

Comment: Does the structure of the database supports this new column? Can you give more details about how you copy the log into the database?

Answer (score 0):

If it's newly added, then I think log parser stops checking the newly defined field after the first 50 entries it finds (perhaps total or per log) try using just the IIS log that has the new field in it to determine if it's working or not. Also, make sure that the first 3 lines reflect the `# Fields: stuff` entire you're looking for.

ie:

`select * from C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC3\todays.log`